# Maintain Facebook auth session for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am a newbie in mobile app development, and am working on my first iOS app.
The concern I have when I integrate FBSDK for authentication is after a while, the token will expire, and the app can no longer perform Facebook actions. What would be the best course of action to handle such case?

I can always make an attempt to login again, but apps such as Facebook app never asks me to login unless I deliberately log out before that.

Comment: The SDKs usually see to it that you get fresh access tokens in the background, when the user is actively using your app.

Comment: Ahhh. That is nice to have. You should make this the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDKs usually see to it that you get fresh access tokens in the background, when the user is actively using your app.

So unless you are experiencing specific problems with access tokens expiring, there should be no need to implement anything special in that regard.